# Allow employers to opt in on a review by users

Tags: feature-request, jobs

I think it might be very helpful to allow employers the chance to opt in on a review of job postings. It would act as a way to help educate employers on what is important to developers as well as creating another avenue for getting job postings read by great developers.

The review results should be private for that employer's eyes only. The point is not to publicly criticize, it is to help employers understand what it takes to hire and keep great developers.

We could also limit the reviewers to those above a given score and even make sure that they have asked/answered questions in the employers development stack. And maybe only make it available to users with a careers profile or who have at least been invited. This would help bring careers.se into the "game" by providing points and/or badges as incentive for the reviews.

I think that employers would really like this option because if the listing is great, then it is getting looked at for an additional reason and by people that are not necessarily currently browsing for a new job. If the listing isn't great they have a better idea of why and how to fix it.